# Getting error: ‘this’ is unavailable for static member functions even when function is not static

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have function, where I create new `pthread` and then work with it later

```
void Client::initialize(Client * c) {
//some unimportant code here
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL,
            c->sendMessage, (void *) fd);
//some unimportant code here
}

Client::Client() {
    initialize(this);
}
```

`sendMessage` function:

```
void * Client::sendMessage(void *threadid) {
    //unimportant code here      
    this->showHelp();
    //unimportant code here
    return NULL;
}
```

declaration of `showHelp`

```
void Client::showHelp() {
    //some code
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get this error:

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb -pthread -lncurses -g -c ./Client.cpp
./Client.cpp: In static member function ‘static void* Client::sendMessage(void*)’:
./Client.cpp:244:13: error: ‘this’ is unavailable for static member functions
make: *** [Client.o] Error 1
```

How is that possible, when `sendMessage` is not declared as `static` ? Is there any way around?

Comment: What is your class definition?  I bet you £1 it declares `sendMessage` as `static`.

Comment: I'll update my post in a minute..

Comment: You probably want `&Client::sendMessage` in your `pthread_create` call as well, though you simply can't pass member function pointers.

Comment: It would be static in declaration... having keyword static in definition is for something else, so don't search in definition when this error occurs :)

Comment: Interestingly you decided to leave out the **declaration** of `sendMessage`, where the `static` specifier would be...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely your `sendMessage` **is** declared as static in class definition. Specific member function definitions are indistinguishable for static and non-static functions. You have to look at class definition to tell them apart.

Comment: Ok...I'm an idiot...I've spent 2 hours seeking what could be wrong and of course I had it declared as static in the header file x-)